# Can't debug when using `docker-compose run`, but `docker-compose up` works

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-debugger

I can create a test repo, if needed.  But the gist of this issue is that I am able to debug a Docker image created by docker-compose, when I use the `up` command.  I am NOT able to debug the same container when using the `run` command.  In both cases, I can see my app start.  The vs code debugger just doesn't seem to be able to connect to the docker container when using `docker-compose run`.

This is similar to my working launch task in vs code (one the debugger can connect to):

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Docker: Debug",
  "runtimeExecutable": "docker-compose",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "up"
  ],
  "port": 9229,
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "restart": true,
  "timeout": 30000,
  "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "remoteRoot": "/app",
  "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js" ],
  "console": "externalTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "showAsyncStacks": true
}
```

My docker-compose file also specifies a command here (`npm run start-app`, for example), with `start-app` having the following definition:

```
nodemon --legacy-watch --watch ./dist/app1 --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --nolazy ./dist/app1/index.js
```

### Why I have a problem:

I don't want a command specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file because I have one image with multiple processes inside.  (There will be one container-per-process, but they all share the same image.)  I currently have this working for a kubernetes deployment and local development run/debug.  I'd like to get this running and debugging in a container by starting the container with a specified command.

I want to be able to run the container and specify which app to run in my vs code `launch.json` file, similar to the below:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Docker: Debug",
  "runtimeExecutable": "docker-compose",
  "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "all",
        "npm",
        "run",
        "start-app"
  ],
  "port": 9229,
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "restart": true,
  "timeout": 30000,
  "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "remoteRoot": "/app",
  "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js" ],
  "console": "externalTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "showAsyncStacks": true
}
```

FYI, the `all` in the arg list refers to the name of my service in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague found the following snippet in the documentation for `docker-compose run`:

> ...the docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service's ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the --service-ports flag

So I changed my arguments for the launch task to include this flag, and it now works.

```
"runtimeArgs": [
    "run",
    "--service-ports",
    "all",
    "npm",
    "run",
    "start-app"
],
```

For re-clarification, `--service-ports` tells docker compose to honor my port mappings in the docker-compose.yml file, which the `up` command does by default.  `all` is the name of my service in the docker-compose.yml file, and the rest of the command is `npm run start-app`, where `start-app` is my custom script in the package.json file.